# What class address is this according to classful addressing

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, cidr

Would it be class B or C, I thought it was class B because the first bit starts with 1 and the second bit is 0, is that correct?

```
10001111000100011010000000000000
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. We have had CIDR for decades. The old address classes are obsolete. You're twenty years too late with this question.

Answer (score 0):

`10001111000100011010000000000000 = 143.17.160.0` , which falls under class B category (128.0.0.0 to 191.255.255.255).
And yes you are right, if the first bit is 1 and second bit is 0, then it is class B.

For more reference, you can go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network